# Add a footer to a PullToRefreshListView: getting a ClassCastException

Tags: android, footer, pull-to-refresh

This is my problem:

```
    private PullToRefreshListView listView_;
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       listView_ = (PullToRefreshListView) view_.findViewById(R.id.lista_tuoivincoli_refresh);
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context_.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    LinearLayout listViewFooter = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.contodeposito_tuoivincoli_tabella_vincoli_footer, listView_, false);
                    ListView tempView = listView_.getRefreshableView();
                    tempView.addFooterView(listViewFooter);

...
}
```

I've this list, inside of it there are some information. In the footer I get numbers and show a total.
First the listView_ was a simple ListView, and everythings worked great.
Changed my xml to this:

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
            android:id="@+id/lista_tuoivincoli_refresh"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="6dp"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
```

Changing the first line from ListView to "com.handmark.pulltorefresh...."
and adding the last 5 lines (used by the pulltorefresh library.

If I comment the line

```
tempView.addFooterView(listViewFooter);
```

the project works perfectly and the refresh works too.

I've tried to add a postDelayed with an Handler like that:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context_.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                LinearLayout listViewFooter = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.contodeposito_tuoivincoli_tabella_vincoli_footer, listView_, false);
                ListView tempView = listView_.getRefreshableView();
                tempView.addFooterView(listViewFooter);
            }
        }, 3000);
```

but this doesn't work.

Every other questions I saw ( and I saw lot of them) suggest to use the getRefreshableView(), but i already use it.

The project crash when he inflate the footer.

Thank you!

EDIT: LOG CAT

```
007-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams  
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.ListView.clearRecycledState(ListView.java:513)  
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:500)  
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1474)  
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2052) 
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11477)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11477)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1644)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1502)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1415)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11477)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1644)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1502)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1415)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11477)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11477)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11477)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1644)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1633)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1417)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11477)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11477)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11477)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at net.simonvt.menudrawer.LeftDrawer.onLayout(LeftDrawer.java:62)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11477)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11477)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1644)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1502)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1415)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11477)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11477)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1692)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2649)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
07-01 12:42:17.530: E/AndroidRuntime(8286):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the LogCat if you can

Comment: I haven't come across this error before, but it's crashing because of this `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()`, try and look for some solutions to that error, and see if any apply to you.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams` Somewhere wrong LayoutParams are being applied. Is `LeftDrawer` a class of yours? If so can you post it's code?

Comment: the code is not mine, you can find it here https://github.com/motain/android-MenuDrawer/blob/master/library/src/net/simonvt/menudrawer/LeftDrawer.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace `listView_` with `tempView`. may be it should work

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        ListView tempView = listView_.getRefreshableView();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context_.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout listViewFooter = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.contodeposito_tuoivincoli_tabella_vincoli_footer, **tempView**, false);

        tempView.addFooterView(listViewFooter);
    }
}, 3000);
```